# Sending bytes over the serial port takes more than 5 minutes

Tags: java, serial-port, rxtx

My Java-Program is having trouble to communicate correctly over one serial port.
In fact, there are two serial ports on the computer and the program manages two thread. Each thread is using one different serial port.
One thread has trouble to send over the port. The bytes are not sent after using `OutputStream.write()` but after the `java.io.OutputStream.flush()` method has been used. And the thread gets "stuck" from 5 to 10 minutes on the `flush()` method. 
The other thread is working the same way but has absolutely no trouble.
The `outputstream` instance comes from `gnu.io.CommPort.getOutputStream()`.

Does anyone has an idea why the thread doesn't send bytes immediately but only after being stuck 5 minutes on the `flush()` method and what I should do differently ?

Comment: When you write to the same place i.e. serial port the resource may be busi or not available if you sinchronize threads to get the status of the channel you could see the difference.

Comment: There is only one thread using the serial port, and no other program. But i found out that if the other device connected on the serial port sends something while my program is stucked on the flush() method, it "unstuck" the program which then sends his message (before recepting the message from the other device)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out what the source of the problem was. The serial port was defect. I replaced it and it works fine now.